# Markdown preformatted fixed-width code block language for variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, markdown, eslint

How to make a Markdown preformatted fixed-width code block for variables?
**I mean code block language**

**Examples:**

`````
`*${variable}*`      // *bold text*        ok
`_${variable}_`      // _italic text_      ok
````${variable}````  // ```pre-formatted fixed-width code block```   not work
`````

Comment: Have you tried putting newlines between the ` chars and the code?

Comment: I got Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your problem boils down to escaping the backticks.

In JavaScript, when you need to use the backtick character inside a template string, you must escape it:

```
const stringWithBacktick = `\``;
```

Hence, your template string might look like this:

```
const preformatted = `\`\`\`${variable}\`\`\``;
console.log(marked(preformatted));
```

Alternatively, you could just join the template string with the triple backticks like this:

````
const preformatted = `${variable}`;
console.log(marked("```\n" + preformatted + "\n```"));
````

Or, in a more reusable way:

````
const preOpen = "```\n";
const preClose = "\n```";
const preformatted = `${preOpen}${variable}${preClose}`;
console.log(marked(preformatted));
````